# AngularJS not validating email field in form

Tags: angularjs

I have the html below where I have a form that I want to submit to the AngularJS Controller.

```
<div class="newsletter color-1" id="subscribe" data-ng-controller="RegisterController">
  <form name="registerForm">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="email" placeholder="your@e-mail.com" data-ng-model="userEmail" required class="subscribe">
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <button data-ng-click="register()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-block">Subsbcribe</button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

And the controller is below

```
app.controller('RegisterController', function ($scope,dataFactory) {


$scope.users = dataFactory.getUsers();

$scope.register = function () {
    var userEmail = $scope.userEmail;
    dataFactory.insertUser(userEmail);
    $scope.userEmail = null;
    $scope.ThankYou = "Thank You!";
}
});
```

The problem is that no validation is taking place when I click the button. It is always routed to the controller although I do not supply a correct email. So every time I click the button I get the {{ThankYou}} variable displayed. Maybe I do not understand something.

Comment: no different than conventional form.. Without a `name` a field will never submit therefore doesn't need to be validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS does not disable enable any functionality for form validations. What is does is, it makes the state of the form and its control in terms of validation available on the current scope. You are required to implement the behaviour yourself.

In your case if you need to check user email is valid your html input should have a name attribute like

```
<input type="email" placeholder="your@e-mail.com" data-ng-model="userEmail" required class="subscribe" name='userEmail'>
```

Then on your controller you can check

`$scope.registerForm.userEmail.$invalid` property.

You can use the same property to disable the button on the form using `ng-disabled`

```
<button data-ng-click="register()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-block" ng-disabled='registerForm.userEmail.$invalid'>Subsbcribe</button>
```

Basically the `registerForm` object is a `ngFormController` and `userEmail` is `ngModelController`. Please read the developer guide for [forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Thank you for your help and the link with the extra info. It worked as intended. I only had to add `novalidate` to the form to make it not display the html 5 errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some part to achieve what you want. Normally you will need to add some code to enable disable the submit button base on the state of the form i.e valid/invalid. In your case this can be done like that :

```
<button data-ng-click="register()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-block" ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid">Subsbcribe</button>
```

Notice the `ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid"`.

You can as well provided inline feedback to the user with something like :

```
<input type="email" placeholder="your@e-mail.com" data-ng-model="userEmail" required="" class="subscribe" name="userName"/>
<span ng-show="registerForm.userName.$error.required">Please enter a name</span>
```

Or with CSS like that :

```
input.ng-invalid-required {
  background-color: #FA787E;
}
```

You have a working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsikwHdgBbup3og7SmGD?p=preview)

Comment: If you ever need to access angular's FormController (the `registerForm` property with all the `.$invalid`, `.$pristine` etc properties), simply place `data-ng-controller="RegisterController"` on the form element. That way, your controller and the directive will share the same `$scope` and you'll have access to `$scope.registerForm` from within `RegisterController` code.